# Call the function again on catch in Parallel forEach

Tags: c#

I have a code like this

```
Task.Run(() =>
{
    ParallelOptions options = new ParallelOptions();
    options.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = (int)(1);

    Parallel.ForEach(addresses, options, (address) =>
    {
        var nr1 = address.Split(new string[] { ":" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[0];
        var nr2 = address.Split(new string[] { ":" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[1];
        DoAddressStuff(nr1 , nr2 );
    });
});

public void DoAddressStuff(string stuff, string stuff2) {
 try {} catch (WebDriverTimeoutException e) {
  // Do Something
 }
}
```

Basically, what I'm trying to achieve. If website takes too long to load, it catches the `WebDriverTimeoutException`, I'm not exactly sure how could I `retry` my already done call to the function.

An example what I'm trying to achive: 
If it calls `DoAddressStuff("data", "data")` and website won't load, then it calls the function again with the same in the Parallel. Can such thing be possible to do?

Comment: In parallel _with what_? Your function isn't actually doing anything more, so your question doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Update the method `DoAddressStuff` to return if it was success or not. something like below

```
public bool DoAddressStuff(string stuff, string stuff2) 
{
bool retval  = true;
  try {} 
  catch (WebDriverTimeoutException e) 
  {
  // Do Something
  retVal = false;
 }
return retVal;
}
```

And then change the call to something like below

```
if(!DoAddressStuff(nr1 , nr2 ));//may be add number of retries
{
   DoAddressStuff(nr1 , nr2 )
}
```